# convert curl to python requests (pisignage API)

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I am trying to convert a curl of [pisignage](https://piathome.com/apidocs) into python requests. The curl is,

> curl -X POST "https://swagger.piathome.com/api/files" -H  "accept:
>   application/json" -H  "x-access-token: login_session_token" -H 
>   "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "Upload
>   file=@test.jpg;type=image/jpeg"

My code is,

```
import requests

files = {'Upload file': open('test.jpg', 'rb'), 'type': 'image/jpeg'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data', 'accept': 'application/json', 'x-access-token': 'login_session_token'}

file_response = requests.post(
    'https://swagger.piathome.com/api/files',
    files=files,
    headers=headers
)
print(file_response)
```

It returns 404. I tried uncurl, the code is:

```
import uncurl

u = uncurl.parse('curl -X POST "https://swagger.piathome.com/api/files" -H "accept: application/json" -H "x-access-token: login_session_token" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "Upload file=test.jpg;type=image/jpeg"')

print(u)
```

The output is ,

> error: unrecognized arguments: -F Upload file=test.jpg;type=image/jpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day of searching it turns out the swagger documentation is incorrect.

use

```
files = {
    'assets': (open('test.jpg', 'rb'))
}
```

Comment: This is so funny. I could not solve it so had to use curl from cmd via python. The solution was not elegent but worked. I am going to accept this answer and if anybody finds this answer useful can upvote it. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  import requests

    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'x-access-token': 'login_session_token',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }

    files = {
        'Upload file': (None, 'test.jpg;type'),
    }

    response = requests.post('https://swagger.piathome.com/api/files', headers=headers, files=files)
```

[link](https://curl.trillworks.com/) to parse curl to request python

Comment: It returns 404.

Comment: There is something with -F "Upload file=test.jpg;type=image/jpeg" 
Anyway, thanks for the help! :)